# Get intime and outtime from the table of a day and particular emloyeeID

Tags: sql-server

I have three columns employeeID, intime and outtime.I want to get only first intime and last outtime of the day.

Table structure:

```
EmployeeID          Intime                       OutTime                    1                2008-01-13 08:10:04.000         2008-01-13 09:03:42.000  
2                2008-01-13 09:10:04.000         2008-01-13 10:03:20.000    3                2008-01-13 08:10:05.000         2008-01-13 09:03:45.000    1                2008-01-13 10:10:04.000         2008-01-13 11:03:42.000    1                2008-01-13 12:10:04.000         2008-01-13 13:03:30.000
```

I want first intime and last outtime

like
Output:

```
EmployeeID          Intime                       OutTime
1                2008-01-13 08:10:04.000         2008-01-13 13:03:30.000
```

What is the sql query for this.
Please give query in written.

Thanks

Dinesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be (assuming OutTime is always in the same day as InTime):

```
SELECT employeeID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Intime, 112) AS TheDate, MIN(Intime) AS InTime, MAX(OutTime) AS OutTime
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY employee, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Intime, 112)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the first intime, last outtime for the current date (you can use any date instead of getdate() in the where clause to get details of any other date).

```
Select employeeid, Min(Intime) as Intime, Max(Outtime) as OUttime 
from Yourtable
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Intime,111) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)  
group by employeeid
```